# Evaluation of a tricky integral involving the pdf of a normal distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution

I tried to evaluate the following integral:
$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-aw}e^{-\frac{(w-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dw.$$
It seems that integration by parts does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

The following answer is given by my instructor:
$$\mu-\frac{a}{2}\sigma^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the square on the other way:
\begin{align*}
  aw+\frac{(w-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} &=
  \frac{w^{2}-2(\mu+a\sigma^{2})w+\mu^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \\
  &= \frac{w^{2}-2(\mu+a\sigma^{2})w+(\mu+a\sigma)^{2}-
     2a\mu \sigma^{2}-a^{2}\sigma^{4}}{2\sigma^{2}} \\
  &= \frac{(w-\mu-a\sigma^{2})^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}-
     a\left( \mu+\frac{a\sigma^{2}}{2} \right) \\
\end{align*}

Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
  && -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 \exp \left[ -aw-\frac{(w-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right] dw \\
  &=&
  -\exp \left[ -a\left( \mu+\frac{a\sigma^{2}}{2} \right) \right]
  \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  \exp \left[ -\frac{(w-\mu-a\sigma^{2})^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right] dw\\
  &=&
  -\sigma \, \exp \left[ -a\left( \mu+\frac{a\sigma^{2}}{2} \right) \right]
  \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\, \sigma} 
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  \exp \left[ -\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right] dx\\
  &=& -\sigma \, \exp \left[ -a\left( \mu+\frac{a\sigma^{2}}{2} \right) \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\frac{w-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}$

$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac{(w-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}-aw\right]dw$$

$$=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-x^2-a(\sqrt{2}\sigma x+\mu)\right]\sqrt{2}\sigma dx$$

$$=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left[-a\mu\right]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-x^2-\sqrt{2}a\sigma x\right] dx$$

$$=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left[-a\mu\right]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\bigg(x+\frac{a\sigma}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^2+\frac{a^2\sigma^2}{2}\right] dx$$

$$=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left[-a\mu+\frac{a^2\sigma^2}{2}\right]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\bigg(x+\frac{a\sigma}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^2\right] dx$$

$$=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left[-a\mu+\frac{a^2\sigma^2}{2}\right]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-x^2\right] dx$$

$$=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left[-a\mu+\frac{a^2\sigma^2}{2}\right]\sqrt{\pi}$$

$$=-\sigma\exp\left[-a\mu+\frac{a^2\sigma^2}{2}\right]$$

Comment: Thank you Kyson. I got to this step as you show here, but I cannot get any further. Can you give more suggestions?